# Polar coordinates and overlapping areas

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, curves

The area of the region that lies inside both curves $r = 1 - \cos \theta$ and $r = \frac{1}{2},$ when simplified, can be expressed in the form
$\frac{a \pi}{b} - \frac{c \sqrt{d}}{e}$

where $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ $d,$ and $e$ are all positive integers. Find $a + b + c + d + e.$

How do I find the proper points of intersection? I think I will need to do that, then find out what angle sector is cut out.

Answer (score 1):

The curves intersect when they have the same $r$ and $\theta$.

You can find $\theta$ by solving the equation $1-\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$.

This will give you two values of $\theta$ where the curves intersect.

Note, you need to make sure you take into account which curve has the lower radius so that you capture the region that lies inside *both* curves.

Answer (score 0):

The two curves intersect at $(\frac12, \pm \frac\pi3)$. Then, the area integral is

$$\frac12\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} (1-\cos\theta)^2d\theta
+\frac12\int_{\pi/3}^{5\pi/3} \frac14d\theta= (-\frac{7\sqrt3}8+\frac\pi2 )+ \frac\pi6= \frac{2{\pi}}3
-\frac{7\sqrt3}8$$

Thus, $a + b + c + d + e=23$.